# Assigning a std::basic_string to a string

Tags: c++, string, casting, stdstring

I have the following existing class in my code:

```
struct Aclass {
    typedef std::string TitleType;
    TitleType title;
    typedef std::size_t NumType;
    NumType some_num;
};
```

After an instantiation of `Aclass`, let's say `aclass`, I set `aclass.title` to some string in my program. In a different function, I want to do the following:

```
NumType new_num;
std::string new_string;

new_num = aclass.some_num;  // this works, verified by print statement
new_string = aclass.title;  // this doesn't work
```

`typeid(aclass.title)` gives a `basic_string` type as expected, but the assignment to `new_string` is causing my program to crash. How can I do this assignment correctly? Is some conversion necessary to transition from `basic_string` back to `string`?

Comment: new is a reserved word
And A is a class not an object.

Comment: That's how to do it, as long as both are valid objects. `new_string` is valid since you've just created it; but we know nothing about `A`. How did you create it, and are you sure it hasn't been destroyed since then? Can you post a complete, compilable example to demonstrate the crash?

Comment: I know the contents of `A.title` are valid. I can print `std::string(A.title)` to verify.

Comment: Just the code you've given doesn't compile; the line `new_string = A.title;` complains that I can't use `.` after the name of a type (or something like that).  What's the real code?

Comment: @squareskittles Can you print `new_string` and `typeid` it?

Comment: yes, it is also the `class basic_string` type. Exactly the same type as `aclass.title`.

Comment: @squareskittles: How do you determine that `A.title` is valid? Could you post a complete, compilable example to demonstrate the crash? Otherwise, we can't begin to guess what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set a.title to NULL or 0, instead of "".  This would cause a crash when you try to assign the string.

A string is (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/):

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

which is a template instantiation of a basic_string with type char.  If you only refer to std::string in your code, there is no conversion necessary.

Other than that I'd suggest using a debugger, such as gdb or ddd in order to trap the error.

Comment: No, `aclass.title` holds the following string "Sample Output". And I can print it using `std::cout << std::string(aclass.title);`

Comment: There is not enough code to find out what is wrong.  You should use a debugger like gdb, or ddd to trap the error.  Also a memory checker tool, like valgrind, could help.